# MySQL - Linking employee(s) to invoice #

Tags: mysql, list, storage

A service company wants a registry of exactly who did what job, in this case we have 9 employees in which one or more employees can do one invoice at a time.

The question is: For management to obtain a query of jobs done by each employee (payroll), how should the database store the invoices an employee has done?

So far the supervisor marks the employees that worked in each invoice, and the db has all 9 employees, I'm having trouble with storing matrices into a column -- or rather a list of employees in a column.

Can this be queried by employee without finding say employee 22 when searching for employee# 2?

```
Invoice #                   List of Employees
 1                        3, 5
 2                        8, 1, 4
 3                        6
 4                        7, 2, 9, 3...
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a pretty basic database question -- have you read a beginning tutorial on relational databases? If so, can you see how your database design can be improved to make this task much, much easier?

Comment: Obviously I'm having trouble setting up the relational database, you're stating the obvious here.

Comment: Now that @koryakinp has set the tables up for you, google "SQL JOIN" for how to retrieve the data you want. Also take some time to read about foreign keys, which is what's going on in the EmployeeInvoice table. Assuming you aren't getting us to do your homework for you, also read about transactions, which will help the integrity of your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE Invoice
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE EmployeeInvoice
(
    [EmployeeId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [InvoiceId] INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ([EmployeeId], [InvoiceId]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeInvoice_ToTableEmployee] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeId]) REFERENCES [Employee]([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeInvoice_ToTableInvoice] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([InvoiceId]) REFERENCES [Invoice]([Id])
)
```